# unable to update, getting some error : ''Errors were encountered while processing: transfig''

Tags: updates

[dpkg: error processing package transfig (--configure):
 package transfig is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 transfig
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tprwL.png)